# If the null space of a $8 \times 6$ matrix is $1$-dimensional, what is the dimension of the row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand how to find the row space, column space, and At space given the rank of the matrix, but how would I find this? Does the dimension just mean the rank? Would the row space be $5$?

Can you give the difference in $1$-dimensional, $2$-dimensional, and $3$-dimensional? This is not a homework problem, it's just something I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the Rank-Nullity Theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem

Comment: Yes, rank A + dim Nul A = n

Comment: Oh geez I think I get it now! How stupid I was. 6 = r + 1 so r=5 right? Is it really that simple?

Comment: What do I do if it is unknown? Say A is 6x4 matrix, what is smallest possible dimension of Nul A? The book says 2 but gives no explanation.

Comment: Linear Algebra by David Lay. I thought 2 also. If there are 4 columns you can have basements and no Nul At. Thanks again, this really helps and I actually understand it!

Comment: Oh, I think you meant A a 4x6 matrix! Then Nul(A) is at least 2 (otherwise rank(A)=dim(row(A))=dim(col(A))>4 which is not possible as the columns are in vector space of dim 4, so the dim of col(A) cannot exceed 4)

Answer (score 1):

The rank of the matrix is equal to the dimension of the rowspace, and also equal to the dimension of the column space.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine that matrix (for example A) as a linear transformation from a space with 6 dimension to a space with 8 dimensions.

So RANK(T)+dime (null(T))=dime (domain of T)

so rank(T)+1=6 so
rank(T)=5
and rank (T)=dimension of row space of A